# Render various document types on a BlackBerry

Tags: pdf, blackberry, viewer, renderer

I need an application which can read a variety of document formats.  I am looking for something that can handle word, excel, powerpoint and pdf.

I want to invoke that application from my application and then return back to my application. Are there any open source or third-party applications available that do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to create application which handles pdf's and other formats or you just need to be able to open docs?

AFAIK there are some pdf viewers but those i have tried are not free.

Comment: Thank you 

It is okay even though they are not free 
But Actually I am looking to invoke that application using my application in some way. I tried Installing one such application(Beam Reader) and tried to invoke BeamReader from myCustomApplication but it didnot work

Can I get any open source document reader for BB and I also know the constructor's name.

Comment: I have used beam reader and it works. If you want to invoke it from your app use the Content Handler API (CHAPI). Look around and  you will find many tutorials on how to use it. Basically some apps register as content handler and other apps(yours for example) are clients. So the client makes request from type "Can someone handle .pdf extensions" and beam reader is registered as a handler and handles the pdf(opens it)